# How do I convert a bunch of factors to ordinals?

Tags: r

I have a bunch of factors that are really ordinals but they're coded as numerics.

This is my code

```
student_performance <-
  read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UBC-MDS/ellognea-smwatts-student-performance/master/data/student-math-perf.csv") %>% 
  as_tibble()


convert.to.ordinals <-
  c("Medu",
    "Fedu",
    "traveltime",
    "studytime")

student_perf %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(convert.to.ordinals), as.factor(ordered = T))
```

I'm trying to organize them as ordinals and get them to be in ascending order, so it would be the same as doing factor(student_performance$Medu, levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4)) except for all of the ones in the list of variable names

Answer (score 3):

In the newer version of `dplyr`, we can use `across` to loop over the column names specified in the vector `convert.to.ordinals`, apply the function to transform i.e. `factor` to modify those columns and assign the output back to the original object to change that object

```
library(dplyr)
student_performance <- student_performance %>%
    mutate(across(all_of(convert.to.ordinals), ~ 
            factor(., ordered = TRUE)))
```

NOTE: The `across` is a generic way to loop over groups of columns and it replaces the `mutate_at` or `mutate_all`, `mutate_if` with certain changes in the `.cols` to specify whether a subset of column names with `all_of` wrapper or `select_helpers` such as `matches`, `starts_with`, `ends_with` or `everything()` (`mutate_all`) or the `where` (`mutate_if`)

---

Or with `mutate_at`, the key is the lambda function (`~` => `function(x)`)

```
student_performance %>%
    mutate_at(vars(convert.to.ordinals), ~ factor(., ordered = TRUE))
```

Comment: What's determining the order for the ordinals? I'm curious if they automatically will be in the order from the q

Comment: @akrun instead of creating lambda functions it would be better to pass the ordered argument through the dots of `mutate_at` (or `across`) like : `mutate_at(vars(convert.to.ordinals), factor, ordered = T) `

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk That is also a good option for compactness

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk Or, even more compact, `help('ordered')`.